# How can i send object/instance of a class from an application on one machine to another application in different machine in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, networking

I am working on a MacOS cocoa application using swift from which i have to send information using an object to another application on different machine which then use the information in it's code.
I am new to swift and sorry for my english if you don't to get it.

I have no idea how to do this. Please help me with this if anyone knows.

Comment: Can you give a little more details, in particular how are the machines connected ?

Comment: they are remotely connected over a network (internet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just so you know network communication can be pretty hard. I believe the easiest way is to use WebSocket, which establish a pipe of communication between two devices. You can then send any data you want over this socket.
One difficulty is for the devices to find one another : do they know each other's IP address ? Are they on the same local network ?

The second step is to decide *what data you want to send*. The simplest is to send JSON content which can be serialized / deserialized on each end easily.

Checkout :

- [tutorial for websocket](https://medium.com/@michaelneas/swift-websockets-78008632e628)
- [JSON Serialization](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)